# Git: driver cloning doesn't work

Tags: ros, git, sick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to clone the driver "sick_tim3xx" for the Sick Laserscanner from the following URL:

```
   kos.informatik.uni-osnabrueck.de/sick_tim3xx.git
```

Unfortunately I get always the error, that the HTTP request failed. Is there another way to install this driver?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58929/git:-driver-cloning-doesn%27t-work/) by [platzhirsch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3129/platzhirsch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems they have been removed all the projects from their git server (or maybe they are doing maintenance tasks). You can check this here: [link text](http://kos.informatik.uni-osnabrueck.de/uos-ros-pkg/?js=1) where a 404 error is displayed saying: No projects found.

I recommend that you contact them directly through its website: [link text](http://www.informatik.uni-osnabrueck.de/kbs/staff.html)

---

Originally posted by [Pep Lluis Negre](https://answers.ros.org/users/4205/pep-lluis-negre/) with karma: 111 on 2013-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1